# Multiple/Different authentication settings in web.config

Tags: asp.net, authentication, web-config, location

How would I go about setting different authentication tags for different parts of my web app?  Say I have:

```
/
/folder1/
/folder2/
```

Would it be possible to specify different `<authentication/>` tags for each folder?

I want folder1 to use Windows authentication but folder2 use Forms authentication.

I tried doing in a `<location/>` tag but it doesn't look like you can have `<authentication/>` tags in a `<location/>` tags, at least not via VS 2008 with it's built in webserver.

This errors out saying - Error  3   It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

```
<location path="/folder1">
    <system.web>
      <authentication mode="Forms" />
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can only have `<authentication />` on the top level `web.config`. You may have to create multiple applications. ie you can create an application within an application and use different authentication modes in each one.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can set the forms authentication authorization on folder1 to

```
<allow users="*" />
```

then control the windows access via setting windows permissions on the folder.

I haven't tried it, but I can't think of why that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

These settings are only valid at the root level of your ASP.Net application.  To use different settings in a sub folder you will need to go into IIS and set that sub folder to be a new application.

Once you done this, the folder will have a different icon in the IIs manager.  Inside your subfolder, create a new web.config file and add the new authentication settings there.

More information available at [Creating Applications](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/1d1c9a73-b4c5-4cfb-ad69-b77fa2e17e19.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: Right, but it seems like in VS2008 debugger, it can't treat these subfolders as application folders, I'll need to test out by pushing to an IIS server

Comment: If you are using the built in Visual Studio web server then yes, you are correct, you will need to set up the application in IIS.