# Web Configuration file in a sub directory gives error

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am using VS 2012 , I want to implement folder level user authentication and authorization, i have following folder/files structure.

[image]

Following is **Admin -> Web.congfig** file.

```
  <system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/login.aspx" timeout="30" defaultUrl="~/default.aspx" cookieless="AutoDetect">
      <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
        <user name="Admin" password="abc"/>
      </credentials>
    </forms>
  </authentication>


</system.web>
 <location path="~/Admin/Admin.aspx"></location>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="*"/>
        <allow users="Admin"/>
      </authorization>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

When i compile the application it gives me the following error message.

**Error:    1   It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.  E:\Kjan\Reports\Admin\Web.config    5**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="~/login.aspx" timeout="30" defaultUrl="~/default.aspx" cookieless="AutoDetect">
  <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
    <user name="Admin" password="abc"/>
  </credentials>
</forms>
```

In you inner web.config file.

Use this on root folder and `<user name="Admin" password="abc"/>` in your inner web.config file.

Some useful links

1. [Multiple/Different authentication settings in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318816/multiple-different-authentication-settings-in-web-config)

If you are woking on different Areas then MVC

1. [Different authentication mode for different areas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734237/different-authentication-mode-for-different-areas)

Comment: You mean <Credential> part be in inner config file while <forms loginUrl = ""> </forms> in root config file?

Comment: @KhuramJan yes. Go though the first link.

Answer (score 0):

try this
select Menu `Build->Configuration Manager`  select Build checkbox